# Nest Camera Video Streaming in VLC player

Tags: nest-api

I have got a public share nest camera address from my friend.
Instead of using a web browser for seeing the video, I want to use a VLC player to video stream. This way allows me to use many other features of VLC to do video analytics on the video.
How to do it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I was able to do this in these steps:

1. Go to the public video share URL. It should be something like this:

   ```
   http://video.nest.com/live/pSgnOZ0s4t
   ```
2. If you use developer tool on chrome and see network traffic ....look for a URL with   .m3u8 in the end... it will be something like this:

   ```
   https://stream-delta.dropcam.com/nexus_aac/37451e60aeac457f9800704f1662147e/playlist.m3u8
   ```
3. Once you get that open that file in a text editor....you will get something like this inside the file

> ```
> #EXTM3U
> #EXT-X-VERSION:3
> #EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=400816,CODECS="avc1.77.31,mp4a.40.2",RESOLUTION=1280x720
> chunklist_w391480529.m3u8
> ```

The stream URL is then

`https://stream-delta.dropcam.com/nexus_aac/37451e60aeac457f9800704f1662047e/chunklist_w391480529.m3u8`

4. Once you have this then install `livestreamer` to extract video like this:

```
livestreamer "hls://https://stream-delta.dropcam.com/nexus_aac/37451e60aeac457f9800704f1662047e/chunklist_w391480509.m3u8" best -o nest_video.ts
```

5. This will save the file to your disk.

I used this to avoid nest aware subscription. Unfortunately, they charge so much for that service. When someone can just save the video to a disk and upload to a cheap cloud option...

Comment: Is it possible to get a local network stream without having to bounce off the internet?

Answer (score 5):

I wrote a page that takes a public Nest video url and returns an HLS media .m3u8 streaming url

[get media url for nest/ dropcam cameras](https://www.ispyconnect.com/userguide-nest.aspx)

Comment: This works as of today on my Nest cam in both iSpy and Blue Iris!  Thanks!

Comment: While this site is awesome and I don't doubt about the good intentions of the author, posting your Nest video URL there implies a request to a bkacend service. e.g: `GET
 https://www.ispyconnect.com/api/Agent/GetNestStreamUri?publicurl=https://video.nest.com/liveaassa/aass`  hence the link could be logged or accidentally leaked.